# Blank space in JSON Value

Tags: java, android, json

I get a string in `JSON` format and I try to get the values. My method works fine, but if the value has a blank space in it, my method cracks up and it rains exceptions. Below is my code:

```
private String getValue(String jsonval)
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonval);
        return jsonObject.optString("id");
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

While this string works fine: `{titleDE=Deutschland, id=10, titleEN=Germany}`
This one makes problems: `{titleDE=Costa Rica, id=10, titleEN=Costa Rica}`
The exceptions says that the blank space is a unterminated object.

Comment: You should have quotes in all of those.

Comment: {"titleDE":"Costa Rica", "id":"10", "titleEN":"Costa Rica"}  this is currect json format. id is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send key and values in JSON string encased within double inverted quotes. Like this - `"key"="string"`.

```
{"titleDE"="Deutschland", "id"=10, "titleEN"="Germany"}
{"titleDE"="Costa Rica", "id"=10, "titleEN"="Costa Rica"}
```

Also observe there is no blank space between *key and =* OR *= and value*. Integer/boolean values can be without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try below JSON :

{titleDE:"Costa Rica", id:10, titleEN:"Costa Rica"}

You can put any json in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and verify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `JSON`:

```
{"titleDE"="Costa Rica", "id"=10, "titleEN"="Costa Rica"}
```

Your problem is that a `String` is either a chain of characters without spaces (bad practice) or a chain of characters placed between `"` and `"`. If you want to use `"` in your `String` use escape character which is most often `\`.

Examples:
`"Deutchland"`, `"Costa Rica"`, `"He said \"whatever\" "`.

Integer value can be without quotes, but it's a good practice to quote them and later cast those Strings to proper numeric types. When you cast `10` from `JSON`, some automatic parsers will cast it to `int` and some will cast to `long`. For this reason, it's better to cast it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Working:

Use:

{
    "titleDE": "CostaRica",
    "id": 10,
    "titleEN": "Costa Rica"
}

Space can be there. No issue. Just use : instead of =

Answer (score 1):

\u200B can be added between the string "lets **say \u200B this** is string added here "---> this unicode (\u200B a) will be ignored  and empty space added between  **say** and **this**